# JQuery Mobile to check if a Div is Expanded or Collapsed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I have a Div that is collapsible using attribute `data-role="collapsible"`

How can I check at any point in time whether the Div is in Collapsed mode or Expanded mode. I tried this but it doesn't work:

```
if ($("#hideshow").is(":collapsed"))
   alert("collapsed");
```

Please note that `:visible` won't work because in both states visible returns true.

Comment: Is there anything that indicates that the element is collapsed like an attribute?

Comment: Also post the HTML code

Comment: Doesn't it work: `if (!$("#hideshow").is(":visible"))` ??? EDIT: thx for your edit ;)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is done via CSS. When a collapsible element is collapsed, it has the class "ui-collapsible-collapsed" added. Use .hasClass() to check it

```
if ($("#hideshow").hasClass('ui-collapsible-collapsed')) {
    alert("collapsed");
}
```

Comment: The only correct answer here (+1). It potentially would have helped if the OP had mentioned _jQuery mobile_ though...

Comment: @Steven: Added JQuery Mobile as per your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Use the getter of [collapsed option](http://api.jquerymobile.com/collapsible/#option-collapsed) for this:

```js
if ($("#hideshow").collapsible("option", "collapsed")) {
  alert("collapsed");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Tested and working!

```
 if (metingblok.collapsible( "option", "collapsed") == false ) {
//then it is closed
}

  if (metingblok.collapsible( "option", "collapsed") == true) {
//then it is open
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to use:

```
if ($("#hideshow").attr('data-role')=="collapsible")
    alert("collapsed");
```

Comment: This answer is wrong.. It would always show as `collapsed`.

Answer (score -1):

This will do the trick:

```
if ($("#hideshow").attr('data-role')=="collapsible") {
  console.log("collapsed");
}
```

Instead of `console.log`, enter whatever you wish as processing.

Comment: This answer won't _do the trick_ it would always show as `collapsed`.

Answer (score -1):

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/tpvMh/)

You can also use data getter/setter function.

```
var isCollapsed = $("#hideshow").data('role') == "collapsible";

if (isCollapsed)
       alert("collapsed");
```

Comment: This answer is wrong.. It would always show as `collapsed`; and I'm not sure what your _demo_ is supposed to be doing?